# Javascript file resizing generating bad base64 string

Tags: javascript, html, base64, filereader

I've been trying to resize images client side (using HTML5) before upload. It resizes it and sends through a base64 string, but it seems to be broken. The base64 string has spaces and line breaks and weird things, even if I take them out, it seems to still be broken.
This is my HTML:

```
        <div class="form-group">
            <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
            <label for="fileToUpload">Select Files to Upload</label>
            <input type="file" id="FileUpload1" name="FileUpload1" />
            <output id="filesInfo"></output>
        </div>
```

And of course my javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {
        document.getElementById('FileUpload1').onchange = function () {
            var files = document.getElementById('FileUpload1').files;
            for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                resizeAndUpload(files[i]);
            }
        };
    } else {
        alert('The File APIs are not fully supported in this browser.');
    }

    function resizeAndUpload(file) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function () {

            var tempImg = new Image();
            tempImg.src = reader.result;
            tempImg.onload = function () {

                var MAX_WIDTH = 400;
                var MAX_HEIGHT = 300;
                var tempW = tempImg.width;
                var tempH = tempImg.height;
                if (tempW > tempH) {
                    if (tempW > MAX_WIDTH) {
                        tempH *= MAX_WIDTH / tempW;
                        tempW = MAX_WIDTH;
                    }
                } else {
                    if (tempH > MAX_HEIGHT) {
                        tempW *= MAX_HEIGHT / tempH;
                        tempH = MAX_HEIGHT;
                    }
                }

                var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
                canvas.width = tempW;
                canvas.height = tempH;
                var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
                ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0, tempW, tempH);
                var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");

                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.onreadystatechange = function (ev) {
                    document.getElementById('filesInfo').innerHTML = 'Done!';
                };

                xhr.open('POST', 'Upload', true);
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                alert(dataURL);
                var data = 'image=' + dataURL;
                xhr.send(data);
            }

        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
</script>
```

The dataURL variable, that's what contains the bad base64 string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is your problem:

Base 64 encoded string includes characters like `/` and `+` , which as you can imagine have special significance if the request content type is said to be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. So, with your current code, `+` sign gets decoded as a space, and combinations like `\n` get interpreted as control characters such as line feed, new line etc.

All you have to do is encode `dataURL` to make sure it is safe for use as a parameter value. This is as simple as using the `encodeURIComponent` method.

i.e. `var data = 'image=' + encodeURIComponent(dataURL);`

Hope this helps.